# Web Server HTTP Header Internal IP Disclosure SOLR port

Tags: solr, pci-compliance, solr6

I am using Apache SOLR 6.6.5 as my search engine and when we do security scan on our server, we got the below response

**When processing the following request : GET / HTTP/1.0 this web server leaks the following private IP address : X.X.X.X as found in the following collection of HTTP headers : HTTP/1.1 302 Found Location: http://X.X.X.X:8983/solr/ Content-Length: 0**

I have checked for more time however haven't find any solutions to fix this problem. Any idea of how to solve this would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would not recommend exposing Solr directly. It should always be behind something that interacts with users or exposes an API. Solr is not designed to be exposed.